# Naming tables within openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

This works good, as I expected:

```
SELECT * FROM Openquery(RETAIL_PROD_UK, 'select LOAN_STATUS FROM lloanall')
```

But why can't I do this? Is it not possible to use joins in openquerys?

```
SELECT * FROM Openquery(RETAIL_PROD_UK, 'select LOAN_STATUS FROM lloanall As l')
```

> Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 An error occurred while preparing
>   the query "select LOAN_STATUS FROM lloanall as l" for execution
>   against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "RETAIL_PROD_UK".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Openquery(RETAIL_PROD_UK, 'select LOAN_STATUS FROM lloanall') As l
```

Now you can do your JOIN like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Openquery(RETAIL_PROD_UK, 'select LOAN_STATUS FROM lloanall') As l
JOIN someTable s ON s.id = l.id
```